# Test for my Application , on nexus 7 and 5

Tags: android

We put our application up on store . We would like to know if its possible to download on nexus 7, and if not what could the problem be due too?

Is there something additional to do onstore, or the app devloped is not compatible with those devices for some reason or the other.

Comment: This looks like a play-store support thing. You should contact their support instead of asking here ;)

Comment: Try to read and understand about [filters on Google Play](http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can check in your menifest file for supported Screen Sizes like this..

```
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

possibly there will not be support for large screen sizes.. change the setting according to your requirement and upload the new build to store..